# Angular Proxy Config "Not rewriting GET /api/account/user because the client prefers JSON"

Tags: json, angular, webpack, url-rewriting, proxy

Having run into a CORS error in Angular v16.1.0 (using port 44498) with a ASPNET CORE DotNet 6.0 backend (using port 44303), I have followed the recommendation of using the Angular Proxy to rewrite a request to the backend URL.  This is my proxy config:

[proxy.conf.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEUco.png)

I call a HTTClient GET in a typescript component:

[HTTPCLIENT GET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnBBs.png)

Nothing happens - the URL is not rewritten and the browser displays an HTTP 404 not found message:

[Chrome 404 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aknxx.png)

I enabled verbose logging and was presented with this message:

[WebPack Error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQBo4.png)

I have researched this extensively and have not been able to find anybody reporting this particular problem, particularly not that specific WebPack error message.  I have found other people reporting the Angular Proxy not working, but in nearly every case it seems that they are not rewriting an HTTPS call.

The expected behaviour is that the URL https://localhost:44498/api/account/user is rewritten to https://localhost:44303/api/account/user so that GET succeeds (as it does when called by POSTMAN.)

Comment: For the proxy to work you need to make the request _to the proxy_.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Jon, but as the proxy is returning an error code, I think that is taken care of.

Comment: facing similar issue. Any luck?